# Reading parquet files in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, parquet

I'm new in hadoop and I need to read a parquet file at map stage of map reduce process. I've found the following snippets of code at cloudera:

```
public static class MyMap extends
  Mapper<LongWritable, Group, NullWritable, Text> {

  @Override
  public void map(LongWritable key, Group value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      NullWritable outKey = NullWritable.get();
      String outputRecord = "";
      // Get the schema and field values of the record
      String inputRecord = value.toString();
      // Process the value, create an output record
      // ...
      context.write(outKey, new Text(outputRecord));
  }
}
```

Job configuration:

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

Job job = new Job(getConf());

job.setJarByClass(getClass());
job.setJobName(getClass().getName());
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
job.setMapperClass(MyMap.class);
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

job.setInputFormatClass(ExampleInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

job.waitForCompletion(true);
return 0;
}
```

The question is Can I use my own type instead of key and value and how to implement it ? I mean sort of pojo which represent one record from parquet file.

Comment: That code is just reading text. Did you look at the Cloudera source code? https://github.com/cloudera/parquet-examples/tree/master/MapReduce

Comment: Yeah, it's the same example.

Comment: Right, so the code you have isn't the same as that link. Reading Parquet as line delimited Text won't work, though you should add `ExampleInputFormat` code to your question

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but if I need my custom type instead of "Group" in map method how can I implement it ? Here is a link to this class https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/example/ExampleInputFormat.java

Comment: I'm not able to find that `Group` class, but have you tried making an InputFormat for `extends ParquetInputFormat<YourClass>`?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about it, but I wanted a confirmation of somebody who aware how to implement such things. Is it right way or not ?

Comment: I've only used Hive, Pig, and Spark to read Parquet. Never mapreduce

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your efforts